# Temporary Files Error generating while build website

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am working on an ASP.NET website. When I build the website I get an error regarding temporary files:

> CS0433: The type 'ABC' exists in both ...

I have removed the temporary files from that location but when building the solution I keep getting the same error for the same type. I also tried `Batch=false` in the web.config which solved my problem but it takes too much time to build and I am not sure if this is the right way.

Is there any way to stop generating temporary files twice for a particular type?

Comment: Which version of Kentico do you use?

Comment: I am using Kentico 9.0. After upgrade from 8.2 to 9.0 I got this problem

Comment: Can you please list the full paths of a few temporary files?

Comment: The type 'ASP.cmsmodules_admincontrols_controls_metafiles_file_ascx' exists in both 'c:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\01421867\784395a8\App_Web_e0loc4j4.dll' and 'c:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\01421867\784395a8\App_Web_file.ascx.f96160db.fq23unbh.dll' ..\CMS\CMSFormControls\Metafiles\MetaFileUploadControl.ascx

Comment: Are you using a **Web Site**, or a **Web Application**?  It may seem like a dumb question - but are you sure that you don't actually have to types with the same sig. after the upgrade from 8.2 to 9?